# sent a post request in actions and commit a data change with vuex

Tags: vue.js, axios, http-post, vuex, commit

I am trying to set a `boolean` to true after submitting a new user with `vuex` but I get a strange error of `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

this is the create method in `actions` `state`

```
        async CREATE_USER({state}) {
                await axios.post('api/user', state.user)
                        commit('SET_CREATED_USER');
        },
```

this is the mutation

```
 SET_CREATED_USER: (state) => {
            state.newUserCreated = true;
            console.log('user create? -> ', state.newUserCreated);
        }
```

and the on submit method

```
onSubmit() {
              this.$store
                  .dispatch('CREATE_USER')
                  .then(() => {
                      this.inProgress = false;
                      // navigate to user
                      this.$router.push('users');
                  })
                  .catch( ({ response }) => {
                      this.inProgress = false;
                      this.errors = response.data.errors;
                      console.log('you have an error on creating an user')
                    });
            },
```

I tried to add `.then` to the `CREATE_USER` method

```
axios.post('api/user', state.user).then(
() => commit('SET_CREATED_USER');
)
```

got the same error
I also tried

```
async CREATE_USER({state}, context) {
                await axios.post('api/user', state.user)
                        context.commit('SET_CREATED_USER');
        },
```

I  also tried to remove the `async` and I get an error

`Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: commit is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. You're trying to use `commit` in your action without access to it

```
async CREATE_USER({ state, commit }) {
    await axios.post('api/user', state.user)
    commit('SET_CREATED_USER');
},
```

2. You're trying to access `response.data.errors` but `response` is a nullable key so it's throwing an error.  You can probably just use optional chaining to handle it.

```
.catch((error) => {
    this.inProgress = false;
    this.errors = error?.response?.data?.errors
    console.log('you have an error on creating an user')
});
```

Comment: @key do you see errors in your browser console?  do you see the http request in your network tab?